# How to use multithreaded operations for different ServiceProtocol - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, nsoperationqueue, swift-protocols

I am trying to use multithreaded operations with OperationQueue in my App.

Indeed, I would like to fetch all my data from all the different webservices during the launch, so that everything is ready to be use when I arrive on the Home page.

But I can't figure out how to properly do it.

**Here is some code to visualize it :**

```
class LauncherService {

    weak var serviceForecast: ForecastServiceProtocol?
    weak var serviceRadar: RadarServiceProtocol?
    weak var serviceWarning: WarningServiceProtocol?
    weak var serviceRain: RainServiceProtocol?

    init(serviceForecast: ForecastServiceProtocol = ForecastService.shared,
         serviceRadar: RadarServiceProtocol = RadarService.shared,
         serviceWarning: WarningServiceProtocol = WarningService.shared,
         serviceRain: RainServiceProtocol = RainService.shared) {

        self.serviceForecast = serviceForecast
        self.serviceRadar = serviceRadar
        self.serviceWarning = serviceWarning
        self.serviceRain = serviceRain
    }

    func requestAllServices(forCity city: City, completion: ((Result<Bool, ErrorResult>) -> Void)? = nil) {

        if let lat = city.lat,
            let lon = city.lon {
            self.fetchForecast(lat: lat, lon: lon)
            self.fetchRain(lat: lat, lon: lon)
        }

        self.fetchWarning()
        self.fetchRadar()
    }
}
```

I would like to wait until all the services have done their work before **"notify"** the HomePage that `evertyhing is ready to go`.

Here is the implementation of the methods from all the different ServiceProtocol :

I will show you only one, but the implementation is exactly the same for all the services :

```
func fetchForecast(lat: String, lon: String, completion: ((Result<Bool, ErrorResult>) -> Void)? = nil) {

        guard let service = serviceForecast else {
            completion?(Result.failure(ErrorResult.custom(string: "Missing service")))
            return
        }

        service.fetchForecast(lat: lat, lon: lon) { result in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch result {
                case .success(let forecast) :
                    // DO something with this Forecast Model Object
                    // Add it in an array on return in completion
                    // But I would like to regroup all the different Model Objects from all my services. 
                    completion?(Result.success(true))
                    break

                case .failure(let error) :
                    print("Something went wrong - \(error)")
                    completion?(Result.failure(error))
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have read that OperationQueue is the solution to adopt here for my use case.

Should I implement something like this ?

```
let queue = OperationQueue()

for service in services {
    queue.addOperation {
        self.fetch()
    }
}

queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DispatchGroup` for that:

```
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    fetchForecast {
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    fetchRain {
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("All done")
    }
```

The last block will execute when both of the request have finished loading.